# How should I include before do in minitest rails3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

What is the syntax for writing before do in minitest ?

I am trying to write a test case using minitest in rails3.2.

In development environment, we are loading this data using some background jobs. so, I have tried to do the same thing in test environment also.
Before running my test suite, I have to run the task in background and generate vibrancy data and the same is being used in the test suite for asserting.
but, it's throwing undefined method `before' for CommunityVibrancyTest:Class (NoMethodError)

```
   require 'test_helper'

   Class CommunityVibrancyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

     before :each do
       App::Queue.add(CommunityVibrancyWorker, communities(:private_community).id )
     end

     test 'to check whether the vibrancy of a private community is handliing share or not' do

       private_community = communities(:private_community)
       share = shares(:share_for_private_microblog)
       stat = share.object
       post_vibrancy = stat.aggregated_score_mblog.round(1)
       assert_equal post_vibrancy, private_community.community_vibrancies.last.post_vibrancy
     end
   end
```

test/unit/community_vibrancy_test.rb:24:in `<class:CommunityVibrancyTest>': undefined method`before' for CommunityVibrancyTest:Class (NoMethodError)
    from test/unit/community_vibrancy_test.rb:4:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `before` with `setup`

Check detailed documentation here https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/SetupAndTeardown.html